# to load a page along with data which is sent through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a view page and a table. When I click view button in the table, the data has to be retrieved from db based on the code and the related data such as name, place has to be displayed based on the code. I'm not able to pass the data after retrieving based on code. The code goes here:

Controller:

```
public function project_show(){//page where all buttons are present
    $this->load->view('view_project');
}

public function view_get_id($pcode){
    $data['viewrec']=$this->project_model->view_proj($pcode);
    $this->load->view('view_project',$data);
}
```

ajax:

```
$('.viewbutton').click(function(){
    var pcode = $(this).data('id');
    $('#viewmodal'+ pcode).modal('hide');
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    console.log(pcode);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/project/view_get_id/"+ pcode,
        data: {
         pcode: pcode,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#viewmodal").modal('hide');
          showproject();
        }
      });
});
```

`showproject()` is a page which opens on successful execution

Model:

```
public function view_proj($Pcode){
    $qresult=$this->db->get_where('Project', array('project_code' => $Pcode));
    return $qresult->row();
}
```

View:
Page where modal pops up:

```
<button class="viewbutton btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewmodal" data-id="<?php echo $row->project_code; ?>"><span class = "fa fa-eye"></span> view</button>
```

Modal page:

```
<div id="viewmodal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" ..>
..........
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Project Code</label>
<label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><?php echo $viewrec->project_code; ?></label>
```

How will i display the data in modal page as the error states like `$viewrec->project_code` undefined or accessing non-object variable

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: Yes. Error was: Trying to get the property of non-object

Comment: In view page check getting data or no

Comment: No i'm not getting and thats the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function view_proj($Pcode){
    $qresult=$this->db->get_where('Project', array('project_code' => $Pcode));
    return $qresult->row();
}
```

you want only 1 result not an array of one result.

also i don't see you doing anything with the returned data in the ajax request. maybe look in to that as well.

Comment: Yes i want only one data and i want to send it to the other view page which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

`row_array` will give single record and `result_array` will give multiple records.

```
public function view_proj($Pcode){
    $qresult=$this->db->get_where('Project', array('project_code' => $Pcode));
    return $qresult->row_array();
}
```